# (BATCH) Add new lines to text files from Echo

Tags: file, batch-file, text, echo

I'm average at Batch and am trying to create a fun program just to see what I can do. I thought it was be cool to have security logs and thought it could echo out .txt logs every time a command is processed, for example:

```
echo %date%, %time%: Started program > securitylog_%date%%time%.txt
```

However, I would like to know how I would ADD lines to the text file, not create a new one every time the echo command is processed (if that makes any sense), for example, the log would end up looking like this:

```
1/1/2015, 12:34pm: Started program
1/1/2015, 12:35pm: Entered password incorrectly "1234"
1/1/2015, 12:35pm: Entered password correctly
1/1/2015, 12:36pm: Menu command "database"
1/1/2015, 12:38pm: Exit back to menu
1/1/2015, 12:39pm: Quit program
```

I have looked at methods however I wasn't sure if they would do what I wanted them to do. What code would I put in to add a new line and add what was in the **echo** to the text file?

Thanks in advance, and I hope it made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double "greater than" symbols to add to an existing file:

```
echo %date%, %time%: Started program >> securitylog_%date%%time%.txt
```

A single one creates a new file each time.

Comment: So it will add a new line every time? (Testing now, thanks for answering)

Comment: Yes it adds a new line. I am not sure how to append without a new line if that is what you are after but I don't think you are based on your original post :)

Comment: I am encountering problems with the creation of the file name, because %date% contains a space. Is there a way to change it to just 05/03/2015, and not Thu 05/03/2015?

Comment: I am not sure off the top of my head as it is many years since I did this stuff, perhaps play around with the date formatting:%date:~0,2%/%date:~3,2%/%date:~6,8% taken from https://pario.no/2007/10/02/formatting-date-in-ms-dos-batch-file/

Comment: spaces are no problem, if you enclose the filename in quoutes: `echo line of text>>"file name with spaces.txt"`. Anyway: if you use `%time%` with the filename: how many entries do you expect to happen in a centisecond?

Comment: Had a chance to test this will give you the date format you want: %date:~4,10% It means take 10 chars of the date field starting from Char 4. as an example of how the string cutting works, this does the same thing: %date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4% taking the parts individually and putting a \ inbetween the parts.